# Error in SQL SELECT with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, basically, I have two tables called "dadoscatalogo" and "palavras_chave", with a common field, "patrimonio" which is the primary key of "dadoscatalogo".

I'm using a servlet to connect to the database with these tables, and passing a query to search for entries based on some search criteria that's defined by the user.

Now, since the user can search for entries based on information present in both tables, I need to do an `INNER JOIN`, and then use `WHERE` to search for that info. I'm also using `LIKE`, because the user may pass just part of the information, and not all of it.

So, to test it all out, I tried passing it a few parameters to work with, and see how it went. After some debugging, I found out that there was some mistake in the query. But I can't seem to be able to point out exactly what it is.

Here's the test query:

```
SELECT dadoscatalogo.patrimonio
FROM dadoscatalogo 
  INNER JOIN palavras_chave 
    ON dadoscatalogo.patrimonio=palavras_chave.patrimonio 
WHERE dadoscatalogo.patrimonio LIKE '%' 
  AND dadoscatalogo.titulo LIKE '%tons%' 
   OR palavras_chave.palchave LIKE '%programming%';
```

So, basically, what I'm trying to do with this query is, get all the primary keys from "dadoscatalogo" that are linked to a record with a "titulo" containing "tons", or a "palchave" containing "programming".

PS. Sorry for the names not being in English, hopefully it won't be too much of a distraction.

EDIT: Right now, the tables don't have much:

This is the dadoscatalogo table:
http://gyazo.com/fdc848da7496cea4ea2bcb6fbe81cb25

And this is the palavras_chave table:
http://gyazo.com/6bb82f844caebe819f380e515b1f504e

When they join, I'm expecting it to have 4 records, and it would get the one with patrimonio=2 in dadoscatalogo (which has "tons" in titulo), and the one with palchave=programming (which would have patrimonio=1)

Comment: Tell us the exact error

Comment: It would be helpful to know what **concrete RDBMS** you're using - Oracle`? MySQL? PostgreSQL? IBM DB2? SQL Server? MS Access? Something else entirely? Please update your tags!!

Comment: `field LIKE '%' ` is a quite nonesensical condition.

Comment: Why LIKE '%', that means just any thing (except NULL, which a primary key can't have...)

Comment: So, what is the problem exactly? You say you've done some debugging and found something wrong, but not shown us any of that. Can you give us an example of input, expected output, actual output?

Comment: Can you post some of the content of those tables which shows some entries which should get matched?

Comment: So which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It's a college assignment, and we're using PostgreSQL. The thing with LIKE '%' is that the professor is requiring us to work with some weird user input, that's why it's there.
But, if I'm seeing things correctly, it shouldn't alter the result if there's an AND after it, right?

Comment: I wonder what weird user input could require this. But you aren't posting any input, so we can not help you anyway.

Comment: As for the debugging, I'm using Netbeans with some breakpoints, and he just stops after reaching "ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);"
All it tells me is "Thread stopped at line etc" which doesn't really help...

Comment: I've edited the question with the table contents and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding run below query:

```
 SELECT dadoscatalogo.patrimonio
FROM dadoscatalogo 
  INNER JOIN palavras_chave 
   ON dadoscatalogo.patrimonio=palavras_chave.patrimonio 
WHERE dadoscatalogo.titulo LIKE '%tons%' 
  OR palavras_chave.palchave LIKE '%programming%';
```

Comment: This works, but it'll probably give me trouble.
The thing with the LIKE "%" is that, the user not only defines the string for each parameter, but also if it's gonna be an AND and OR, like this: http://gyazo.com/b628329ea4dd4f3e05dceaea46a12dda

Me and my classmates think this is a weird design to put up for a user, but the professor just said "be creative", so I was putting the "AND" or "OR" as a prefix in the query (that's why I put the LIKE '%', since without it there'd be an "AND" or "OR" just floating there)

Comment: But I guess I'll have to work without that then, thanks!